# Phonegap, Cordova watchposition fire success every 1 second

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

Platform: iOS6/OSx Lion.

I'm trying to puzzle out the way Phonegap/Cordova work with `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`.

The docs says that the option "`maximumAge`" is the one that ask the system for retrieve the position.

So with these options:

```
{ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }
```

I espect the position request will be fired every 3 seconds?

And no matter what `maximumAge` I put the success is fired every 1 second...

Anyone can explain please?

Thanks Bye
Rob

Comment: same issue here. Cordova 2.2 and iOS 5.1 / iOS6 . iOS fires every one second, Android seems to do it every 30, but is not quite reliable.

Comment: Hi nickhar, so it doesnt work also in Android? It's really strange i was thinking that i'm using the wrong paramters, in previous versions of Cordova/Phonegapp there was a "frequency" parameter.
Thanks Ciao
Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently working around this issue by using `getCurrentPosition` with a `setInterval`. I'm not sure what the consequences may be, but this seems to give me the most control and appears to be the most consistent method across platforms.

```
// call this once
setupWatch(3000);

// sets up the interval at the specified frequency
function setupWatch(freq) {
    // global var here so it can be cleared on logout (or whenever).
    activeWatch = setInterval(watchLocation, freq);
}

// this is what gets called on the interval.
function watchLocation() {
    var gcp = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            updateUserLoc, onLocationError, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });


    // console.log(gcp);

}

// do something with the results

function updateUserLoc(position) {


var location = {
    lat : position.coords.latitude,
    lng : position.coords.longitude
};

console.log(location.lat);
console.log(location.lng);
}

// stop watching

function logout() {
    clearInterval(activeWatch);
}
```

Comment: Hi Scald,
Thanks for the reply. In fact seems that the function watchPosition it's just a call (with timer) to getCurrentPosition (i've looked inside cordova.js).
Btw Your code it's very helpfull! When You stop the timer with "clearInterval(activeWatch)" it's stop also the "watchPosition"? I mean if call many times "setupWatch" maybe there will be many timers  with "watchPosition"?? Thanks a lot Ciao Rob

Comment: Rob-- there isn't a watchPosition being used in my code. I understand that somewhere below the surface cordova might be doing something similar but this is working a lot better for me than their `watchPosition` call. Yes, the `clearInterval` call stops the `watchLocation` and clears that timer so that subsequent calls to `setupWatch` can create a fresh timer.

Comment: Hi Scald, Thanks i will try Your code i'm pretty sure that's the cordova.js has some problems with iOS. Thanks a lot! Ciao Rob

Comment: Hi Scald,
I've tried Your code and it works. The problem is that the getCurrentPosition does not work when the app is in background. So i can't use for tracking gps position. I've looked into the Android source code of Phonegap and here seems to be implemented the "maximumAge" parameter (in GeoBroker.java line 67) in iOS source code there's no reference to "maximumAge"! I've created a thread in Phonegap Google group maybe this need to be posted as a bug to Phonegapp Github. Thanks a lot Ciao Rob

Comment: Hi Scald,
Answer accepted. Shazron from Phonegap has replied to me with the portion of code that is mean to governate the maximumAge option (see: http://goo.gl/SDTj7). Btw seems to me that this not mean to set the timing of retrieving the current user location, but getting the last cached one over the new one (seem futile?) so the gps device it's still operating every one second...
Gotta try some other ways... maybe firinng a timer on the watchPosition with Your code? Anyway thanks ciao Rob

Comment: I am also having this issue, and find calling getCurrentPosition on a timer to have best results. Related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136082/geolocation-watchposition-stops-firing-after-an-error