# geolocation.watchPosition stops firing after an error

Tags: cordova

On Cordova 3.6, with IOS SDK 8.1, I am observing that after calling geolocation.watchPosition, I may get either 1-2 geolocationSuccess results, or a geolocationError (kCLErrorDomain error 0, or timeout). If I get those 1-2 success results, then nothing else fires again until an error timeout. After the error, nothing else fires again. If I call clearWatch and watchPosition again, then the process repeats.

What is going on here? I would expect to keep getting periodic geolocationSuccess calls, and if there is a geolocationError then I should at least keep getting updates either with success or failure. Why does the event firing stop, and I have to reset it by creating a new watch? I actually get the best results by just calling geolocation.getCurrentPosition periodically using my own timer.

I did notice in the debugger that the location manager delegate is logging "locationManager::didFailWithError (null)" right after calling watchPosition, even if I later get geolocationSuccess.

This occurs on both iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1, as well as iPod Touch 4 running iOS 6.

The relevant code is straightforward:

```
var geoWatchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
    geolocationError, {
        maximumAge: 5000,
        timeout: 60000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });
```

Comment: We need code to help.

Comment: I pasted the code for watchPosition in above.

Comment: How about with the iOS Simulator - do you see the error there?

Comment: that might be a bug, file an issue on the cordova JIRA